# Reshaping data.table with cumulative sum

Tags: r, data.table

I want to reshape a data.table, and include the historic (cumulative summed) information for each variable. The `No` variable indicates the chronological order of measurements for object `ID`. At each measurement additional information is found. I want to aggregate the known information at each timestamp `No` for object `ID`.

Let me demonstrate with an example:

For the following data.table:

```
df <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 No=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4), 
                 Variable=c('a','b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'),
                 Value=c(2,1,3,3,2,1,5))
df
   ID No Variable Value
1:  1  1        a     2
2:  1  2        b     1
3:  1  3        a     3
4:  2  1        c     3
5:  2  2        a     2
6:  2  3        a     1
7:  2  4        b     5
```

I want to reshape it to this:

```
       ID No  a  b  c
    1:  1  1  2 NA NA
    2:  1  2  2  1 NA
    3:  1  3  5  1 NA
    4:  2  1 NA NA  3
    5:  2  2  2 NA  3
    6:  2  3  3 NA  3
    7:  2  4  3  5  3
```

So the summed values of `Value`, per `Variable` by `(ID, No)`, cumulative over `No`.

I can get the result without the cumulative part by doing

```
dcast(df, ID+No~Variable, value.var="Value")
```

which results in the non-cumulative variant:

```
   ID No  a  b  c
1:  1  1  2 NA NA
2:  1  2 NA  1 NA
3:  1  3  3 NA NA
4:  2  1 NA NA  3
5:  2  2  2 NA NA
6:  2  3  1 NA NA
7:  2  4 NA  5 NA
```

Any ideas how to make this cumulative? The original data.table has over 250,000 rows, so efficiency matters.

EDIT: I just used a,b,c as an example, the original file has about 40 different levels. Furthermore, the `NA`s are important; there are also `Value`-values of 0, which means something else than `NA`

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Okay, so I've found a working solution. It is far from efficient, since it enlarges the original table.

The idea is to duplicate each row `TotalNo - No` times, where `TotalNo` is the maximum `No` per `ID`. Then the original dcast function can be used to extract the dataframe. So in code:

```
df[,TotalNo := .N, by=ID]
df2 <- df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), (df$TotalNo - df$No + 1))] #create duplicates
df3 <- df2[order(ID, No)]#, No:= seq_len(.N), by=.(ID, No)]
df3[,No:= seq(from=No[1], to=TotalNo[1], by=1), by=.(ID, No)]
df4<- dcast(df3, 
            formula = ID + No ~ Variable, 
            value.var = "Value", fill=NA, fun.aggregate = sum)
```

It is not really nice, because the creation of duplicates uses more memory. I think it can be further optimized, but so far it works for my purposes. In the sample code it goes from 7 rows to 16 rows, in the original file from 241,670 rows to a whopping 978,331. That's over a factor 4 larger.

**SOLUTION**
Eddi has improved my solution in computing time in the full dataset (2.08 seconds of Eddi versus 4.36 seconds of mine). Those are numbers I can work with! Thanks everybody!

Comment: You could potentially do `cols <- sort(unique(df$Variable)) ; res <- dcast(df, ID + No ~ Variable, value.var = "Value", fill = 0L)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = cols, by = ID]` if you don't mind having zeroes instead of `NA`s

Comment: Zeroes are not an option; there are also values of 0 which have a different meaning than NA. Thanks for contributing though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is good, but you're adding too many rows, that are unnecessary if you compute the `cumsum` beforehand:

```
# add useful columns
df[, TotalNo := .N, by = ID][, CumValue := cumsum(Value), by = .(ID, Variable)]

# do a rolling join to extend the missing values, and then dcast
dcast(df[df[, .(No = seq(No[1], TotalNo[1])), by = .(ID, Variable)],
         on = c('ID', 'Variable', 'No'), roll = TRUE],
      ID + No ~ Variable, value.var = 'CumValue')
#   ID No  a  b  c
#1:  1  1  2 NA NA
#2:  1  2  2  1 NA
#3:  1  3  5  1 NA
#4:  2  1 NA NA  3
#5:  2  2  2 NA  3
#6:  2  3  3 NA  3
#7:  2  4  3  5  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a standard way:

```
library(zoo)

df[, cv := cumsum(Value), by = .(ID, Variable)]
DT   = dcast(df, ID + No ~ Variable, value.var="cv")

lvls = sort(unique(df$Variable))
DT[, (lvls) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), by=ID, .SDcols=lvls]


   ID No  a  b  c
1:  1  1  2 NA NA
2:  1  2  2  1 NA
3:  1  3  5  1 NA
4:  2  1 NA NA  3
5:  2  2  2 NA  3
6:  2  3  3 NA  3
7:  2  4  3  5  3
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way to do it is using a custom built cumulative sum function. This is exactly the method in @David Arenburg's comment, but substitutes in a custom cumulative summary function.

EDIT: Using @eddi's much more efficient custom cumulative sum function.

```
cumsum.na <- function(z){
 Reduce(function(x, y) if (is.na(x) && is.na(y)) NA else sum(x, y, na.rm = T), z, accumulate = T)
}

cols <- sort(unique(df$Variable))
res <- dcast(df, ID + No ~ Variable, value.var = "Value")[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum.na), .SDcols = cols, by = ID]
res

   ID No  a  b  c
1:  1  1  2 NA NA
2:  1  2  2  1 NA
3:  1  3  5  1 NA
4:  2  1 NA NA  3
5:  2  2  2 NA  3
6:  2  3  3 NA  3
7:  2  4  3  5  3
```

This definitely isn't the most efficient, but it gets the job done and gives you an admittedly very slow very slow cumulative summary function that handles NAs the way you want to.

Comment: this will be crazy slow - you have a double loop inside your function

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this isn't giving me the expected output...I tried substituting in `cumsum.na <- function(z) {Reduce(function(x, y) sum(x, y, na.rm = T), z, accumulate = T)}` and I get 0's instead of NAs in rows 2 and 3 for column "c".

Comment: true, it doesn't work correctly - well then add an indicator to keep track of first non-NA value or smth in your loop instead of adding a second loop (just to clarify - the second loop is `all(is.na(x[1:i]))`)

Comment: a fix for the `Reduce` is `Reduce(function(x, y) if (is.na(x) && is.na(y)) NA else sum(x, y, na.rm = T), your_vec, accumulate = T)`

Comment: you have another inner loop left - `sum(x[1:i])`